# Diferencia entre instalar la app desde PC y descargar la app desde playstore

Tags: app

Estoy desarrollando una app clon de Uber. Si la instalo desde el PC funciona bien. Si la subo a play store con appbundel... Y la instalo en mi celular la app crashea al iniciar sesión. Genera el siguiente código de error en playstore.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que me arroja google play console es el siguiente:

```
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass (CustomClassMapper.java)
  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue (DataSnapshot.java)
  at com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire.getLocationValue (GeoFire.java:6)
  at com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery.childAdded (GeoQuery.java)
  at com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery.access$000 (GeoQuery.java)
  at com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery$1.onChildAdded (GeoQuery.java)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent (ChildEventRegistration.java)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire (DataEvent.java:2)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run (EventRaiser.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:236)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7864)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:620)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

Comment: La app funciona perfecto si la instalo desde Android studio con el PC. Pero si la borro del celular y la descargo de la playstore crashea al iniciar sesión... Es la misma app... Las mismas líneas de código todo exactamente igual. No entiendo porque si la descargo de Playstore crashea

Comment: Por favor pon el mensaje de error como texto, será más fácil de analizar. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por tu apreciación. He subido el código que me arroja la Google Play Console...

Comment: Suena a que estás implementando [ofuscación/minificación del código de tu aplicación](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code?hl=es-419). Si es así, debes indicar en el archivo de reglas de ProGuard cómo se van a serializar/deserializar los objetos de tu modelo. Para más detalles [revisa la documentación de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard).

Comment: Yo hace un par de semanas, hice lo de la ofuscacion porque me aparecia una alerta que me decia que no se habia ofuscado el archivo... no habia caido en cuenta que tambien tiene como 2 semanas el problema. Esto porque pruebo la app con dispositivos que tengo en casa, no instalandolos desde playstore. Voy a quitar lo de ofuscacion a ver si funciona bien. Si es asi, gracias a ti ya se que mas adelante tengo que mirar lo de la implementacion de la ofuscacion detenidamente. Gracias. En el proximo post informare de los resultados.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo. Elimine las reglas de ofuscacion y ya funciona a la perfeccion la app. Mas adelante vere como cuadrar lo de implementar estas reglas de manera adecuada para poder cumplir con este detalle.

Comment: A mi juicio, la ofuscación aparece como algo complejo. Recuerdo en el pasado haber intentando ofuscar/minificar el código, todo funcionaba a la perfección al depurar, pero al subir la App a Google Play Store, la misma no abría en ningún dispositivo. Si quieres ofuscar/minificar tendrías que leer cuidadosamente la documentación al respecto (dos enlaces de comentario anterior) y luego subir una versión beta a Play Store y probarla antes de pasar a producción.

Comment: Yo hasta el momento estoy subiendo mi app, sin ofuscar y trabaja muy bien. El problema es que aparece una alerta en la play store que me indica que debo hacer la ofuscacion. Mi pregunta es: Si termino de desarrollar mi app, ¿puedo darla a conocer al publico sin ofuscar?

Comment: Puedes subir la App sin ofuscar, siempre y cuando no exceda los límites en tamaño para una aplicación (que es 100MB actualmente). Si tu App excede ese tamaño, entonces debes separar aquellos recursos pesados y ofrecerlos en descarga una vez el usuario haya instalado la App. [Aquí tienes más detalles sobre todo este tema](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files).